Movie involving an accident with an airliner that causes it to rise out of control
The live-action movie involved an airliner that was somehow damaged (mid-air collision?), jamming the flight surfaces and causing the plane to rise out of control.
The ending involved them filling the front landing gear bay with water(?) from another aircraft (mid-air refuelling plane?) to force the nose down and allow them to land, which I believe they managed safely.
I think I saw the movie on TV in Canada sometime in the mid-to-late-90s.

@AnkitSharma - Refuelling is a perfectly valid spelling of the word

Ohh...sorry for that.

@AnkitSharma - I'll direct my annoyance towards spellcheckers that default to American English and don't have a dictionary for Canadian English.

I am quite a stuck in a state where i mis-merge American English with British English. If i am not wrong Canadian English=British English?

@AnkitSharma - Not quite.  We tend to pick and choose between British and American spellings seemingly at random.  We use airplane rather than aeroplane  and realize rather than realise, but colour rather than color and centre rather than center.  Here's a comparison between the three.

Found it.  What I was remembering was the 1997 film Final Descent.

An airliner collides with a light plane just after takeoff, causing its elevators to jam in the full climb position. It will crash as soon as the fuel runs out, unless some desperate measure succeeds in bringing the nose down. 


Just from the title, this sounds like Starflight: The Plane that Couldn't Land (1983), which includes a "hypersonic" plane which is damaged by an exploding satellite which causes it to go into orbit. The landing is not quite as described in the question, but it still sounds like a fairly close match.

No, that's definitely not it.
